PWA with create react app loads with a white screen when opened from the background on mobile
My PWA built with Create React App often opens with a white screen (of death) when opened from the background in Android and iOS when it has been backgrounded either for a while, or backgrounded whilst heavier apps have run in front of it.
I have plugged my android in via USB and remote debugged, but nothing shows as it appears to be a rendering issue. The service worker is unaffected.
Apart from remote debugging, is there anything else I can do to see what is causing this?
Phone is Samsung S10 which was a flagship device in 2018 or 2019 with reasonably high specs even for today.
Phone has 8gb ram which is what most phones even today have.
Any help much appreciated and rewarded.
